# Getting file on AWS S3 without bucket being public with Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm working with S3 files with Laravel.

My S3 has no public access, but Laravel is configured with a AWS User that has admin rights on S3.

So, I can upload a file in S3 with no problem.

My issue comes from getting file from there.

If I use:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->url($this->path);
```

I will generate a link with format:

```
https://bucket.s3.region.amazonaws.com/path/filename.pdf
```

But as public access is not allowed on S3, it will give me

```
Access Denied
```

If I use

```
Storage::disk('s3')->get($this->path);
```

I can download the data from file, but don't know what to do with it.

EDIT: It seams that doing:

```
Storage::disk('local')->put(
    'filename.txt', 
    Storage::disk('s3')->get('cloud-filename.txt'));
```

Will copy the S3 file in storage folder. Now, how should I generate a working link ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried generating temporary urls?

```php
// link will expire 5 hours from now.
$expires_at = now()->addHours(5);

Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl($this->path, $expires_at);
```

For your second question, I think it should be the other way around:

```php
// retrieve file 'filename.txt' from local disk and put it on s3 disk as 'cloud-filename.txt'
Storage::disk('s3')->put(
    'cloud-filename.txt',
    Storage::disk('local')->get('filename.txt')
);
```

Comment: I saw the temporaryUrl in docs, but didn't realise it was for my use case. Nice ! Thanks for that. I don't need the second one.